# How to Render Blob on visualforce Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Base 64-encoded binary data and I want to render that as an image on a `Visualforce Page`. Is that possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 12):

This is a really interesting question which showcases some powerful (though not necessarily recommended) platform capabilities. To answer it:

**BlobController.cls**

```
public class BlobController {
  public String getData() {
    return
      'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAzklEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyWYgWoGwMEFBi0g' +
      'XgLEb4H4FxD/BuLXQNwHxPwwZdgNuMDgDcS3GR4w7Gf4yfCE4T8UgtggsQsMH4DYHrsBFxiUgfgVw1eG' +
      'm3CN6BAkd4HhGhArYTNgDtiW/wQgxCVTsBnwCcXZuCBIzQWGB9gM+EdQMwxeYPiGzYD/JBjwFZsBz0jw' +
      'wh1sBswiIRAbsBkgDsTviIjGpyC1uBKSJRBfx5OQLgOxLu6UCDFEEYh7oQnmCyjEgfgeELcAsSzOpDxg' +
      'uREA1co5dU5YrgAAAAAASUVORK5CYII='
    ;
  }
}
```

**Blob.page**

```
<apex:page controller="BlobController">
    <apex:image value="data:image;base64,{!Data}" />
</apex:page>
```

[image: Base64 data to image]

## Genericizing this with a component:

Potentially, this could be used (eg) to minimize HTTP requests in overhead-critical applications such as mobile clients. Without the need for a build process. This use of PageReference.getContent may be contentious, and you'd need to consume SOQL queries to properly surface the MIME types, but this works for example's sake:

**DataUriForResourceController.cls**

```
public class DataUriForResourceController {
  public String path {
    get; set;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return EncodingUtil.base64encode(new PageReference(this.path).getContent());
  }
}
```

**dataUriForResource.component**

```
<apex:component layout="none" selfClosing="true" controller="DataUriForResourceController"><!--
--><apex:attribute required="true" name="path" type="String" description="Path for the static resource whose content will be fetched, eg '/resource/myResourceNameZip/file.ext'" assignTo="{!path}" /><!--
-->data:image;base64,<apex:outputText value="{!Data}" escape="false" /><!--
--></apex:component>
```

## Usage:

**JustInTimeCss.page**

```
<apex:page contentType="text/css" cache="true" expires="300">
  div.panel {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background-image: url('<c:dataUriForResource path="{!URLFOR($Resource.myPng)}" />');
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
  }
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i've tried this out for similar kind of scenarios, and was successful to display the encoded signature in the visualforce page, but it is not working if the page is rendered as pdf. Please help me out

Answer (score 9):

What format is the image in? Assuming it's a png file you could do the following:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<<base 64 data here>>"/>
```

The tricky part though, is that you won't be able to nest an `<apex:outputText>` inside there without getting errors from the compiler.

It's a little hacky, but you can assign that string to a variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var theImage = "<apex:outputText value='{!theBlob}'/>";
```

And then assign the full string to the src property of the `img` element (using jQuery here):

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#theImage").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + theImage);
});
```

This code has just been written in browser so is untested, but it should help you get to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

See EncodingUtil for swapping between Base64 and Binary.  You could probably set the entire body of the VF page to the binary/blob version and then set the ContentType of the page component to the appropriate mime-type.