# convert Base 64-encoded binary data to image

Tags: soap, base64

I am having the Base 64-encoded binary data suppose  for 50 image and i want to render that as image on visualforce page using repeat. I used

```
      <apex:repeat value="{!objectName}" var="img" id="theRepeat">
        <apex:image id="theImage" value="data:image/png;base64,{!img}" width="80" height="80"/>
   </apex:repeat>
```

It is giving me error

```
SOAP Fault: Inline data exceeds the maximum allowed size
```

Answer (score 1):

Was just checking out [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/5892/605) and it looks like you did everything correctly. This is just a guess, but I wonder if you would be better served not using an [`<apex:image>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_image.htm). Have you tried just using the [`<img>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) tag directly? Some of the images being used may be bigger than `<apex:image>`'s value was ever intended to work with. I'd try:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!objectName}" var="img" id="theRepeat">
     <img id="theImage" src="data:image/png;base64,{!img}" width="80" height="80"/>
</apex:repeat>
```