# How to fetch images from external system in a callout

Tags: apex

I need to access images from external system using HTTP callouts and display them in Salesforce.
Content-Type →image/png is the format of the reponse Salesforce is receiving
Can we use Blob to store images?Could anyone throw light on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [refer this article](https://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/saving-the-contents-of-an-image-or-file-url-and-saving-to-an-attachment-or), which saves blob as image in Apex.

Example :

```
HttpResponse res = null;
res = h.send(req);
//These next three lines can show you the actual response for dealing with error situations
string responseValue = '';
responseValue = res.getBody();
system.debug('Response Body for File: ' + responseValue);
//This is the line that does the magic.  We can get the blob of our file.  This getBodyAsBlob method was added in the Spring 2012 release and version 24 of the API.
blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();

Attachment n = new Attachment();
//You will want to tie your attachment to some type of custom or standard object
//n.ParentId = myAccount.Id;
n.Name = 'myImage.jpg';
n.Body = image;
//If we were saving a PDF as an attachment the ContentType would be 'pdf'
n.contentType = 'image/jpeg';
insert n;
```

Comment: Thank you Jitendra for prompt reply.Is there a way we can show it on UI without storing it into database?Please advise

Comment: Hi Suneel ,You just need to put URL in the src if you need image to display from URL  <apex:image value="{!imageurl}" />

Comment: Mohith, I do not want to expose an image which is a static resource or with a URL.I am receiving the image from external system into a blob variable.Can you let me how to do that?

Comment: I have used base64encode method of EncodingUtil class to acheive this as mentioned in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5892/how-to-render-blob-on-visualforce-page